# Machine-specific webapp configuration

Tags: spring, tomcat, properties, configuration-files, environment

I have several webapp projects (Java/Spring/Tomcat). Each project will be deployed on several machines as a `.war` file. I need to have separate `.properties` file for each project on each machine. How to implement it?

Beforehand thankfull!

Comment: Spring profiles can be used for exactly this purpose.  They are talked about (for this use case) here: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys in all these configuration files are the same and they differ only in value, I would name the configuration files as `<hostname>.<function>.properties` and maintain machine-specific configuration in these.

While launching the web server that runs these `war` files, I would have a JVM parameter that holds the value of the machine where it is being run. The location where these properties files are read will read this JVM parameter and forms the name of the actual file and loads the properties from that file. Typically, this is done in a single `ConfigurationRepository` kind of a `Singleton` class that gets initialized when the first access to this object happens from anywhere in the code. HTH.